# How to open URLs in new tab in config.yml of Jekyll / Github pages site?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-bootstrap, jekyll-paginator

I'm self-taught/totally new to Jekyll and Github Pages and was wondering how to go about opening a URL in a new tab with markdown in the config.yml page.

[This](https://aweekj.github.io/Kiko-plus/) is the website theme I'm using. **I want the last 'github' link to open in a *new* tab, instead of the default, which is opening in the current tab.**

The _config.yml looks like this:

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # #
#   K i k o - p l u s   #
# # # # # # # # # # # # #

# Basic
name:         "Kiko Plus"

author:
facebook:         your-id
youtubeUser:      your-id
youtubeChannel:   your-id
twitter:    your-id
github:     your-id
stackoverflow:    your-id
quora:      your-id
linkedin:         your-id
pinterest:        your-id
googlePlus:       your-id
instagram:        your-id
reddit:     your-id
medium:     your-id
tumblr:     your-id
email:      your-id@your-email.com

copyright:
year:       2017
name:       Kiko

# Google-analytics
google-analytics:
id:         ""

# Disqus
disqus:
id:         "kiko-plus"

# URL
url:          "https://AWEEKJ.github.io" # the base 
hostname & protocol for your site
# url:          "http://localhost:4000" # use this url when 
you develop
baseurl:      "/Kiko-plus" # the subpath of your site


# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
timezone:     Asia/Seoul
permalink:    /:year-:month-:day/:title/

# Pagination
paginate:     5
paginate_path:      /page:num/

# Markdown
markdown:     kramdown
kramdown:
input:      GFM

# Navigation
nav:
- name:     "About"
  url:      "/about"
- name:     "Archive"
  url:      "/archive"
- name:     "Tags"
  url:      "/tags"
- name:     "Github"
  url:      "https://github.com/AWEEKJ/Kiko-plus"

# Sass
sass:
sass_dir:         _sass
style:      :compressed

# Scopes
defaults:
-
  scope:
    path:         ""
    type:         "pages"
  values:
    layout:       "page"
-
  scope:
    path:         ""
    type:         "posts"
  values:
    layout:       "post"

# jekyll-seo-tag, 
gems:
- jekyll-seo-tag
- jekyll-paginate
- jekyll-admin

exclude:      [vendor]
```

To do this in any basic markdown post, naturally you'd do

```
[a link](http://example.com){:target="_blank"}
```

But since this link is in the site setup, that doesn't work. I've searched a ton and tried 5 or 6 different recommendations but to no avail.

Any ideas? Would be uber appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add  `target="_blank"` to `index.html` line `12` as follow:

```
 <a href="{{ nav.url }}" target="_blank">{{ nav.name }}</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

I found a plugin that automatically sets any external URL to open in a new tab:

https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll-target-blank

> Add the following to your site's Gemfile
>
> ```
> gem 'jekyll-target-blank'
> ```
>
> and add the following to your site's
> _config.yml
>
> ```
> plugins:
>   - jekyll-target-blank
> ```

You may also need to run `bundle install` to install the new Gem

Comment: Worked like a charm for my Jekyll site! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`{:target="_blank"}` works for me:

```
[text](http://url){:target="_blank"}
```