# What is the syntax to create a pdf link in _config.yml

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I am using Jekyll to create a personal website. I am using the [Beautiful-Jekyll template](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll) that is very popular. There is a navigation bar already defined in `_config.yml`. I want to make Resume link to my resume pdf.

I have accomplished that with this code (in `_config.yml`):

```
# List of links in the navigation bar
navbar-links:
  Moi: "aboutme"
  Projects:
    - Hell Game: "http://deanattali.com/beautiful-jekyll/"
    - Success City: "http://www.markdowntutorial.com/"
  Resume: "Tech Resume.pdf"
```

However, this only opens the resume in the same tab. I want it to open in a separate tab. In HTML, you achieve this by using `target="_blank"`. How do I do this in YAML?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003852/how-to-open-urls-in-new-tab-in-config-yml-of-jekyll-github-pages-site) but my `index.html` actually doesn't use links. I know, weird.

Comment: The linked template certainly [does use links](https://github.com/daattali/beautiful-jekyll/blob/master/_includes/navbarlink.html#L16) for its navbar items, it's just in an included file and not directly in the `index.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beautiful-jekyll/_includes/nav.html line 26:

```
<a href="{{ linkparts[1] | relative_url }}">{{ linkparts[0] }}</a>
```

Change it into:

```
<a href="{{ linkparts[1] | relative_url }}" 
{% if linkparts[1] contains '.pdf' %}target="_blank"{% endif %}
>{{ linkparts[0] }}</a>
```

Or use this (java)script/solution:
https://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/new-window-fix/